# leftMargin attribute of LayoutPrams in custom component

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, ontouchlistener

I have a custom component which extends LinearLayout and implements onTouchListener

This component makes some changes to the graphics when onTouch fired and alters leftMargin attribute of the custom view

When I add my component to the project without overriding the onTouch method, everything seems to be working, but when i override the onTouch method, the left margins state becomes relative to the width of the screen.

Why is it like that?

[image]

Custom component:

```
    @Override
    public void setOnTouchListener(OnTouchListener l) {
        super.setOnTouchListener(l);

        navigationButton.setonTouchListener(l)
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
       .....
       return true;
    }
```

Activity:

```
    CustomComponent customComponent = (CustomComponent)findViewById(R.id.custom_component);
    customComponent.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(.....  // This part leads to the change in leftMargin of the customComponent
```

**EDIT:**
Now edited code a little:
*Before:*

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="64.67dp"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical" >


            <com.est.bla.bla.customcomponents.SomeCustomComponent
                android:id="@+id/someid"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
                android:layout_width="100dip"
                android:layout_height="50dip" >
            </com.est.bla.bla.customcomponents.SomeCustomComponent>
```

*Now:* (Now it works right)

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="64.67dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" >


            <com.est.bla.bla.customcomponents.SomeCustomComponent
                android:id="@+id/someid"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
                android:layout_width="100dip"
                android:layout_height="50dip" >
            </com.est.bla.bla.customcomponents.SomeCustomComponent>
```

So I guess that in this particular case, `layout_alignParentRight="true"` is better than  `gravity="right"`

Comment: Can you post an example of what's happening? Some code and pictures will help. Also, could you please edit your question and break the first paragraph up into more than one sentence? It's hard to parse exactly what you're saying.

Comment: @TedHopp, i certainly can, thought that was a common problem which i dont know about

Comment: Please post the layout xml file. Does the margin change when you attach the OnTouchListener, or when the touch event is processed? If the latter, then it will be important to see the code for the OnTouchListener.

Comment: @TedHopp when i attach the onTouchListener

Comment: Normally, that should not happen. Does your custom component override `setOnTouchListener`?

Comment: @TedHopp, yes, as it is shown in the question

Comment: maybe the problem is somewhere else

Comment: Sorry--I missed that you had posted that code. What is `navigationView`, and does it also override `setOnTouchListener`?

Comment: @TedHopp Navigation view is aka Custom component. Same thing, changed it in code, sorry for misspell

Comment: Wait -- `CustomComponent.setOnTouchListener` calls itself? That can't be right.

Comment: yes, this is wrong again. CustomComponent has Button, so instead of CustomComponent.setOnTouchListener i have navigationButton.setonTouchListener which is the part of the CustomComponent and onTouch i am changing this button leftMargin, now it is the way i have it, sorry again for missmissspell

Comment: Well, if `navigationButton` is a standard button, I don't see how this could be happening when you call `setOnTouchListener`. I think you're right that the problem may be elsewhere.

Comment: @TedHopp thank you for your help, i found a possible problem, it is something else